# Laravel 8 - Livewire page expired on mobile phone

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I use Laravel 8 with Livewire and on my mobile phone, when I search an article, I have this error : The page has expired due to inactivity...

The website is https://www.yubigeek.com/, you can make a search from search bar, it's a Livewire component.

#### My .env config file:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

This error come only on mobile phone, on my Chrome browser, I haven't this error.

[image]

Comment: Which livewire version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

@pirmax Many people have complained on GitHub about sudden session expiration this week.

According to Caleb, creator of livewire, "We recently implemented a pretty big internal security feature that may have caused issues."

See a recent comment from him on GitHub issue [Session expire after 30s-1min when using livewire components directly with Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2475#issuecomment-775976568)

He suggests, to either downgrade to version 2.3.8 or it's recent update 2.3.18.

Comment: I'm on 2.3.8 and the 2.3.18 not working properly because I have always this error...

Comment: @pirmax Try changing `SESSION_DRIVER` to `file` and try again.

Comment: Did you clear the config with `php artisan config:clear` after changing the value?